# recognizing punctuation in Tesseract OCR

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am running tesseract to extract text from PDF files in a context where it is important to distinguish between semicolons and commas.
I find that semi-colons often show up as commas after OCR.  The accuracy is otherwise pretty good.
I am looking for suggestions on how to improve accuracy in semicolon versus comma detection.  Following [this](https://electricarchaeology.ca/2014/07/15/doing-ocr-within-r/) suggestion, my procedure is to first convert a multipage PDF file to a ppm file using pdftoppm from Xpdf, then convert that to tif using imagemagick, then run tesseract on the .tif file.
I have set the resolution of the ppm file to 1000 DPI and used the `-sharpen` option in imagemagick in an effort to improve resolution, but neither seems to improve the semi-colon recognition.

Any suggestions for pre-processing the image files or is this just an tough hill to climb?

Here are links to the original [PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45922619/ocr/camp-01.pdf), the [.ppm](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45922619/ocr/camp-01.ppm) and [.tif](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45922619/ocr/camp-01.tif) files, and the [.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45922619/ocr/camp-01.txt) output.
Note that this is copyrighted material which I do not own.

Comment: Can you share the image thst you are processing as well as the processed image?

Comment: added those files...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always custom train the tesseract according to your dataset. You can check this article [How to custom train tesseract](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-a-custom-tesseract-ocr-model-as-an-alternative-to-google-vision-ocr-for-reading-childrens-db8ba41571c8).

But for sure it will be a long process to train a new model by collecting
dataset first and all but it's a way to improve the OCR.